# how to use optional and filter along to retrieve an object from chained/cascaded objects generated by wsdl2java

Tags: lambda, java-8, stream, wsdl, option-type

I understand flatMap is recommended when dealing with hierarchical objects in Java, particularly while extracting values from objects created out of XML files.

Whithout relying on Optional and since getCommercieleNaam() will bring me a list, I coded:

```
NaamOndernemingLijstCommercieelType naamOndernemingLijstCommercieel = onderneming.getNamen()
        .getCommercieleNamen();
NaamOndernemingType naamOndernemingType = naamOndernemingLijstCommercieel.getCommercieleNaam().stream()
        .filter(x -> x.getTaalcode().getValue() == "nl").findFirst().get();
```

In few words, it will walk throw the cascade object and return the first name found for language Netherlands. I see this as very unsafe and, instead of checking all objects if they are null, I prefer to use Optional.

Then I try code what I understand it is the correct way but I don't know how to apply filter in order to retrieve only the object from the list matching a criteria (language == "nl" in my scenario):

```
    Optional<NamenOndernemingType> optionalNamenOnderneming = onderneming.getNamen(); 
    NaamOndernemingType naamOndernemingType = optionalNamenOnderneming.flatMap(NamenOndernemingType::getCommercieleNamen)
            .flatMap(NaamOndernemingLijstCommercieelType::getCommercieleNaam)
            .filter(x -> "nl".equals(x.toString()));
```

PS.: in dutch, naam means name (singular) and Namen means names (plural)

Well, the closest I got was

```
    Optional<NamenOndernemingType> optionalNamenOnderneming = Optional.ofNullable(onderneming.getNamen());
    List<NaamOndernemingType> listNaamOndernemingType = optionalNamenOnderneming
            .flatMap(NamenOndernemingType::getCommercieleNamen)
            .map(NaamOndernemingLijstCommercieelType::getCommercieleNaam);
```

But it is neither working and after I fix this, I need to filter also.

*edited

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "NamenOndernemingType", propOrder = {
    "maatschappelijkeNamen",
    "afgekorteNamen",
    "commercieleNamen"
})
public class NamenOndernemingType {

...

    public NaamOndernemingLijstCommercieelType getCommercieleNamen() {
        return commercieleNamen;
    }


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "NaamOndernemingLijstCommercieelType", propOrder = {
    "commercieleNaam"
})
public class NaamOndernemingLijstCommercieelType {
...

    public List<NaamOndernemingType> getCommercieleNaam() {
```

[image]

*** Solution ***

```
Optional.ofNullable(onderneming.getNamen()).map(NamenOndernemingType::getCommercieleNamen)
                .map(NaamOndernemingLijstCommercieelType::getCommercieleNaam).get().stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .filter(x -> x.getTaalcode().getValue() == "nl").findFirst()
                .ifPresent(o -> myMethod("onderneming_commerciele_naam", o.getNaam().getValue()));
```

PS.: future readers my find worth read my other question as weel: 
[how use Optional with cascaded objects not created with Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262770/how-use-optional-with-cascaded-objects-not-created-with-optional)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Aominè recommendations and to the discussion based on [how use Optional with cascaded objects not created with Optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262770/how-use-optional-with-cascaded-objects-not-created-with-optional)

I reached this solution:

```
Optional.ofNullable(onderneming.getNamen()).map(NamenOndernemingType::getCommercieleNamen)
                .map(NaamOndernemingLijstCommercieelType::getCommercieleNaam).get().stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .filter(x -> x.getTaalcode().getValue() == "nl").findFirst()
                .ifPresent(o -> myMethod("onderneming_commerciele_naam", o.getNaam().getValue()));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a *map* here considering you've said that `getCommercieleNaam` returns a `List<NaamOndernemingType>` therefore once we flatten that we will have a `Stream<NaamOndernemingType>` which we can then find all the objects that have `"nl"` as their string representation.

```
List<NaamOndernemingType> listNaamOndernemingType = optionalNamenOnderneming
           .flatMap(NaamOndernemingLijstCommercieelType::getCommercieleNaam)              
           .filter(Objects::nonNull)
           .filter(x -> "nl".equals(x.toString()))
           .orElse(null);
```

given that an `Optional` doesn't have `collect` as a *terminal* operation we can simply use `orElse` to return the value if present, otherwise return `null`. in this case *value* is a `List<NaamOndernemingType>`.

note -  you'd only need to call *flatMap* if you want to change a `Stream<Stream<R>>` to a `Stream<T>` otherwise you just want a call to *map* which would return a `Stream<R>`.

Comment: Maybe I didn't express correctly when I said getCommercieleNamen() returns a list. Please, see the error I a, getting after your suggestion and getCommercieleNamen() pasted above;

Comment: @JimC see edit and also from your screenshot you have typos i.e in my code I didn't write `Object::nonNull` i wrote `Objects::nonNull`

Comment: @JimC the names of your variables are very confusing as they're all very similar. nevertheless, the gist of it is shown within my post. you need not add any more intermediate operations. therefore just make sure the correct type of data is being passed into `flatMap`.

Comment: I see two Eclipse complains. 1 The method flatMap(Function<? super NamenOndernemingType,Optional<U>>) in the type Optional<NamenOndernemingType> is not 
  applicable for the arguments (NaamOndernemingLijstCommercieelType::getCommercieleNaam). 2 - The type NaamOndernemingLijstCommercieelType does not define getCommercieleNaam(NamenOndernemingType) that is applicable here. Please, could you help me at least understand what could be the reason for Eclipse validator complains so I have a start point for fixing them?